# How can I update a postgresql column of type varchar[] with a javascript array of strings?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, postgresql

I have a postgresql table that includes a column called "tags" with datatype varchar[]. I want to update the value in the "tags" column with a javascript array of strings. My client side is in Javascript and the server side is in Java.

There are no issues if I make the column a varchar datatype instead of varchar[] and then on the client side I first parse the tags to a single comma separated string. However, we prefer to have the column hold an array.

I am first passing an object called person to a Java method that prepares an sql query. Person.values includes my Javascript array of strings along with values for the other columns. The other values are strings and ints and have no issues.

This is the Java method that takes the person.values object and creates an sql query...

```
@POST
    @Path("{listid}/{personid}/update")
    public Message updatePerson(@PathParam("listid") int listid, @PathParam("personid") int personid,
            @NotEmpty Map<String, Object> person) {

        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append("update table_");
        buf.append(listid);
        buf.append(" set ");

        boolean first = true;
        for (String col : person.keySet()) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                buf.append(',');
            }
            buf.append(col);
            buf.append("=?");
        }

        buf.append(" where personid=?");

        ArrayList<Object> args = new ArrayList<>(person.values());
        args.add(new Integer(personid));
        int count = db.sql(buf.toString(), args.toArray()).execute().getRowsAffected();
        if (count <= 0) {
            String err = "Failed to update person with personid: " + personid;
            logger.error(err);
            throw new BadRequestException(err);
        }

        return Message.success("Person updated");
    }
```

I have tried passing the raw javascript string array. I have tried passing a JSON array after performing stringify on the array.

```
JSON_string = JSON.stringify(javascript_array_of_strings)
```

I have also tried parsing the array to match the syntax laid out in the Postgres docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/arrays.html

```
if (fieldname == "tags") {
        fieldvalue = JSON.stringify(fieldvalue);
        fieldvalue = fieldvalue.substring(1,fieldvalue.length-1);
        fieldvalue = "{"+fieldvalue+"}";
        }
this.person[fieldname]=fieldvalue;
```

Here is the exact error I continue to see...

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type character >varying[] but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to >rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 72

UPDATE:
Looked at this a bit further. From testing directly in postgres, I know that this command syntax successfully updates the tags value in the table.
From testing directly in postgres, I know that this command syntax successfully updates the tags value in the table.
UPDATE public.table_53 set tags='{"tag1", "tag2"}' where personid=1

I'm working on figuring out the format in which the JS must output the tags array to the service in order for the service to output the above yellow-highlighted syntax.

I first tried with a JSON array. [, ]
 Java reads this as an ArrayList object.

and the query causes this error...

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an >instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to >specify the type to use.
>   I'm reading up on setObject().

I also experimented with outputting the tags as  '{"",""}'. 
This does not work because the Java replaces the single quotes with double quotes.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type character >varying[] but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to >rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 63

Finally, I tried the same again but added backslashes to escape the quotes. "\'{\"tag1\", \"tag2\"}\'"
This didn't work either... I think the problem is the query still has double quotes around the value.

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is of type character >varying[] but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to >rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 63

Comment: why don't you print your StringBuilder content?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the stringbuilder content. ```"update table_46 set personid=1,firstname="j",lastname="j",email="j@gmail.com,tags="{"tag1","tag2"}" where personid=1"```